# Database entries existence depends on time

Tags: mysql, database, time

I have this situation here.

- An auction system listing orders that are "active" (their deadline didn't occur yet)
- There is a lot of orders so it is better to have a field "active" instead of listing them based on time queries

I'm not a database expert, just a user. What is the best way to implement this scenario ?

- Do I have to manually check the "deadLine" field and change "active" status every once in a while ?
- Is Mysql able to change the field automatically ?
- How demanding are queries of type "select orders where "deadline" has passed "
- Is it better to use boolean criterion or timestamp criterion for searching ? it's like 0,05% active 9,95% passive entries

Finally I have to move old order entries to a different backup table. My point is make the table lightweight, because there could be many requests per second. I'm not sure how much load does it put on the database, whether it there is a difference between criterion like boolean and time for searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to an awful lot of work to solve a problem there's no evidence that you have.  Especially if you're going to be archiving older records off, why don't you make sure that you can't do the time-based searches before you create an entire system dedicated to maintaining a second column that performs the same function as the time column.

If you do decide that you need to keep a separate list of active auctions consider doing it not with a special column (and largely wasted index) but rather by creating an active_auctions table that contains only the primary key column(s) from auctions.  Add a row to this table for each auction that becomes active and delete it when it becomes inactive.  JOIN this table to the main auction table for a list of currently active auctions.

Comment: I did some thinking and came to the end that the flag field is a nonsense. That's absolutely great idea Larry, thanks a lot. This way I won't have to have a thread that once in a while move inactive orders to a backup table. A big problem is, that in the point when order expires, there is no way how to remove it from the order-id table. see it ? if I wouldn't have the order-id table, I would be listing only orders which expiration time haven't passed yet. But in order-id table when order expires, how would I remove it ? Based on what ?

Comment: I put it there when it is created, but to remove it I'd still have to check on expiration time at some point and remove it

Comment: That is correct.  You will still need either a) as task that periodically executes some version of the command DELETE FROM active_orders WHERE order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE expiration < NOW()) or b) you will need to execute that command from whatever code you use to get back the active orders from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second bullet point is dubious:

> There are a lot of orders so it is better to have a field "active" instead of listing them based on time queries.

It probably is better to have an end time for the 'order' and then query for active orders by looking for current time before end time.  The active field will give you lousy selectivity if you index it (a bitmap index might be better).  Additionally, you have to update the rows to change them from active to inactive - and you could do things with active orders past their deadline because the active flag did not get changed in time.

1. Yes, you would have to poll for active flags that should be inactive - using precious DBMS query bandwidth.
2. No, it can't change the field automatically.
3. The UPDATE necessary is worse than just selecting.
4. Yes, you need something like an end timestamp.

Moving old orders to secondary storage (something other than the main table, not necessarily outside the DBMS, let alone on tape) is quite probably a good idea.  It is also not time critical; you can do it at any time after the order has ceased to be interesting.